# Equivalent of  a PATH variable for IPython?

Tags: python, ipython

Say I have a python script `test.py` in some path `path_A`

And say I have an IPython shell open in a path `path_B`.

I would like to be able to do:

```
run test.py
```

from `path_B` (where the shell is open).

Is that possible in IPython? Is there anything like a `PATH` variable in IPython?

Comment: You can `cd path_A` within IPython. Or specify `run path_A/test.py`. I can't think of another option off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3):

Not how you describe.  The usual way is to `os.chdir(path_A)` within ipython first, or just run `path_A/test.py` as Thomas said in the comments.

Adding the PYTHONPATH environment variable, as suggested in another answer here, will not work for `run` because this is only used for searching for `import` modules.

An alternative, is to put `path_A` into `sys.path` (you can do so using PYTHONPATH environment variable, or preferably, in the ipython config file which runs at startup).  Then you would be able to do:

```
import test
test.main()
```

This method would necessitate you to restructure your code in `test.py`, so that it ran at call time rather than at import time.